# How to format an ObservableField (double) DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

So, I have the very simple problem, that I cannot seem to format a double coming from an ObservableField in a data binding. I have the following layout:

```
android:text='@{String.format("%.2f€", transaction.value)}'
```

and here the definition of transaction.value:

```
public final ObservableField<Double> value = new ObservableField<>();
```

I always get this error:

> java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != android.databinding.ObservableField

I get the same issue if I use an ObservableDouble. The only way to avoid this seems to be if I call `transaction.value.get()` in the binding, but I was under the impression that get/set can be omitted here, as I am successfully doing e.g. with an `ObservableField<Date>`.

I am targeting Sdk 26 with with buildTools 26.0.2.

**Update 1**

I tried the same thing now with my previous setup, and it worked, just as I remembered. So I pinpointed it to the Gradle version change from 2.3.1 to 3.0.1 (even when I put in target/compile Sdk 26 and buildToolsVersion 26.0.2 with Gradle 2.3.1 it works).

As @dominicoder pointed out to look into the generated data bindings, here is the difference, explaining the problem:

Gradle 2.3.1:

```
android.databinding.ObservableField<java.lang.Double>transactionValue=null;
java.lang.Double transactionValueGet=null;
....
if(transaction!=null){
    // read transaction.value
    transactionValue=transaction.value;
}
updateRegistration(3,transactionValue);
if(transactionValue!=null){
    // read transaction.value.get()
    transactionValueGet=transactionValue.get();
}
// read String.format("%.2f€", transaction.value.get())
stringFormatJavaLangString2fTransactionValue=java.lang.String.format("%.2f€",transactionValueGet);
```

Gradle 3.0.1:

```
android.databinding.ObservableField<java.lang.Double> transactionValue = null;
// NO transactionValueGet field !!!
....
if(transaction!=null){
    // read transaction.value
    transactionValue=transaction.value;
}
updateRegistration(3,transactionValue);
// read String.format("%.2f€", transaction.value)
stringFormatJavaLangString2fTransactionValue=java.lang.String.format("%.2f€",transactionValue);
```

So - it looks like this is a bug introduced in that version update (to be safe, I created a completely new project with a similar setting, a TextView having its text bound to an `ObservableField<Double>` using `String.format()`). Or maybe it is intended behavior, but I really wouldn't understand the purpose of that kind ob breaking change.

**Update 2**

Currently the problem is filed in the [Android issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70139194)

Comment: I always find it better to bind a string in the XML and do the formatting in the java code, you can unit test it and stuff

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

Check the databinding generated java file for your layout. You will find something like this:

```
android.databinding.ObservableField<java.lang.Double> transactionValue = null;
// read String.format("%.2f€", accountViewModel.test)
stringFormatJavaLangString2fAccountViewModelTest = java.lang.String.format("%.2f€", transactionValue);
```

You can see that it's using the observable field literally and I *think* it's because the signature of `String.format` is `(String string, Object args...)`. Because the observable field is an `Object` it can be used as is, so the code generator does not try to "get" the double value instead.

The Date formatting example works because the `format` method has a signature of `(Date date)`. Thus, the code generator realizes that the signature doesn't match, but the observable type does, so it "get"s it for you and you'll see something like this:

```
java.util.Date transactionDateGet = null;
// read transaction.date.get()
transactionDateGet = transactionDate.get();

androidTextFormatDateFormatGetDateFormatContextFormatTransactionDate =
    android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(
        getRoot().getContext()).format(transactionDateGet);
```

#### The Solution

As you already indicated, the easiest thing to do is just manually call `.get()` in your binding. However, I'd recommend avoiding doing logic in your XML, as @elmorabea indicated. Instead, I'd suggest using a view model that encapsulates the display logic:

```
public class TransactionViewModel {
    private final Transaction mTransaction;

    public TransactionViewModel(@NonNull Transaction transaction) {
        mTransaction = transaction;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getTransactionValueText() {
        return String.format("%.2f€", transaction.getValue());
    }
}
```

Then you have something like this:

`android:text='@{viewModel.transactionValueText}'`

This is more work as you have to have an extra class for each layout file; you'd have to move your observable fields from your models to the viewmodels; and you'd have to make your view model obvserve the model to propagate the changes up the to view, but the separation of concerns makes it far easier to update, extend, reuse, and maintain in the long run.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm using `android:text="@{DateFormat.getDateFormat(context).format(transaction.date)}"` where `transaction.date` is of `ObservableField<Date>`. By that logic this also shouldn't work, since DateFormat.format(Date) shouldn't accept ObservableField<Date>. But the binding should be targeting the ObservableField in any case, otherwise the UI couldn't be notified about changes (wouldn't be a binding, but just once reading a value and printing it).

Comment: This piqued my curiosity so I dug in a bit more. See updated with my findings and suggestion.

Comment: I updated my question with some more findings to that

Comment: If the behavior changed it was either a) intentional so the tools don't make assumptions about how you want to use a method that takes any `Object` or b) a bug, which you should file and ask about at b.android.com.

Comment: Already filed it, seems other people ran into problems of similar nature.

Comment: Could you link to that? I'd be interested in following the issue.